# geometric mean while calculationg tensorflow loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, loss-function

I need to calculate Aitchison distance as a loss function between input and output datasets.

While calculating this mstric I need to calculate geometric mean on each row (where [batches x features] - size of a dataset during loss ).

In simple case we could imagine that there is only 1 batch so I need just to calculate one geomean for input and one for output dataset

So how it could be done on tensorflow? I didn't find any specified metrics or reduced functions

Comment: Is it an option [https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/GeometricMean](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/GeometricMean)?

Comment: I didn't find any examples of usage, when I tried by myself tf.metrics.GeometricMean,  python didn't find it "tensorflow.keras.metrics has no attribute 'GeometricMean'"

Comment: It is not part of the core tensorflow package, but an so called addon. you should first install it. See: [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons).

Comment: yes, I done it, but it looks like I can't use it in way I need. For example when I call  geomean.update_state(yTrue) I got error. So I don't know how use it as part of loss funciton

Comment: Alright, then it seems the metric cannot be used as a loss function due to different API. In that case geometric mean have to be calculated directly with tensorflow functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily calculate the geometric mean of a tensor as a loss function (or in your case as part of the loss function) with `tensorflow` using a numerically stable formula highlighted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099542/python-easy-way-to-do-geometric-mean-in-python). The provided code fragment highly resembles to the `pytorch` solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59722983/how-to-calculate-geometric-mean-in-a-differentiable-way) that follows the abovementioned formula (and [scipy implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/1cc8beed5362ed290f5a8ddf4e99db49b4de6286/scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py#L268-L271)).

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

def gmean_loss((y_true, y_pred, dim=1):
    error = y_pred - y_true
    logx = K.log(inputs)
    return K.exp(K.mean(logx, dim=dim))
```

You can define `dim` according to your needs or integrate it into your code.